# Testing many scenarios - inserting to test DB manually from test method

Tags: php, phpunit

I want to test everything that happens inside the controller's method, based on different database initial states. The problem is that I'd have to have a lot of different initial database sets in one test, and then test for different outputs. For example:

```
public function testSomeAction() {
   $sc = new SomeController();

   $user = new User(1, null, date('Ymd'));
   $sc -> someAction();
   $this -> assertTrue(1, $this -> getConnection() -> getRowCount('user'));

   $user = new User(1, 'aaa', null);
   $sc -> someAction();
   $this -> assertTrue(0, $this -> getConnection() -> getRowCount('user'));
}
```

And so on. It's ok until I need to add database input and don't have insert method in my code - I then have to include it in the dataset. But I don't want this, because I use the same dataset in other tests.

So the question is - **can I make insert to test database manually from the test method?**